# Dynamic programming and Dijkstra

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

I'm reading the following problem statement meant to be solved with dynamic programming:

> Given an undirected graph G having N `(1<N<=1000)` vertices and positive weights. Find the shortest path from vertex 1 to vertex N, or state that such path doesn’t exist.
>
> Hint: At each step, among the vertices which weren’t yet checked and for which a path from vertex 1 was found, take the one which has the shortest path, from vertex 1 to it, yet found.

I believe the algorithm should be something like

```
S = starting point
N = ending point
initialize all distances from S to +infinity
unexplored_vertices[] = [all vertex adjacent to S]

for each v in unexplored_vertices[]
  calculate new_distance from S to v
  if new_distance is better than the former then
    store new_distance
  closest_to_v = find(unexplored_vertices[], closest_to_S)
  unexplored_vertices[].add_front(closest_to_v)

return distance from S for N
```

Anyway this is very similar to how [Dijkstra's algorithm works](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) for shortest paths.

My question is: am I getting the problem statement wrong or is the statement really asking (along with the hint) for Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm?

Comment: Yes, seems like the hint is guiding you torwards Dijkstra's Algorithm.